# Bulma Modal not responsive on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog, bulma

I have a question regarding the Bulma Modal. I set up everything like it said [in the documentation](https://bulma.io/documentation/components/modal/), however "on click" the Modal does not open. I found that the Modal is there, however it is hidden (as per default), but the javascript when I press the button is not triggered. I ran a console log, which shows that the js is actually connected to the file, but it does not react when I click on the "Modal trigger button"... Any ideas as to why this happens, or what I should change in my code to make the modal appear active?

Here is the Code:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  console.log('Hello Bulma!');
});

// Chat functionality
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const chatBtn = document.querySelector('#chat-btn');
  const chatContainer = document.querySelector('#chat-container');
  const chatClose = document.querySelector('#chat-close');
  const tabItems = document.querySelectorAll('.tabs li');
  const tabPanels = document.querySelectorAll('.tab-panel');

  chatBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    chatContainer.classList.toggle('is-active');
    if (chatContainer.classList.contains('is-active')) {
      chatBtn.style.display = 'none';
    }
  });

  chatClose.addEventListener('click', () => {
    chatContainer.classList.remove('is-active');
    chatBtn.style.display = 'block';
  });

  tabItems.forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener('click', () => {
      const tabId = item.dataset.tab;
      const tabPanel = document.querySelector(`#${tabId}`);

      tabItems.forEach((item) => {
        item.classList.remove('is-active');
      });

      tabPanels.forEach((panel) => {
        panel.classList.remove('is-active');
      });

      item.classList.add('is-active');
      tabPanel.classList.add('is-active');
    });
  });
});

// Tabs functionality
const tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.tabs li');
const tabContentBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('#tabs-content > div');

tabs.forEach((tab) => {
  tab.addEventListener('click', () => {
    tabs.forEach((item) => {
      item.classList.remove('is-active');
    });

    tab.classList.add('is-active');
    const target = tab.dataset.target;
    tabContentBoxes.forEach((box) => {
      if (box.getAttribute('id') === target) {
        box.classList.remove('is-hidden');
      } else {
        box.classList.add('is-hidden');
      }
    });
  });
});


// Modal
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  // Functions to open and close a modal
  function openModal($el) {
    $el.classList.add('is-active');
  }

  function closeModal($el) {
    $el.classList.remove('is-active');
  }

  function closeAllModals() {
    (document.querySelectorAll('.modal') || []).forEach(($modal) => {
      closeModal($modal);
    });
  }

  // Add a click event on buttons to open a specific modal
  (document.querySelectorAll('.js-modal-trigger') || []).forEach(($trigger) => {
    const modal = $trigger.dataset.target;
    const $target = document.getElementById(modal);

    $trigger.addEventListener('click', () => {
      openModal($target);
    });
  });

  // Add a click event on various child elements to close the parent modal
  (document.querySelectorAll('.modal-background, .modal-close, .modal-card-head .delete, .modal-card-foot .button') || []).forEach(($close) => {
    const $target = $close.closest('.modal');

    $close.addEventListener('click', () => {
      closeModal($target);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.4/css/bulma.min.css">
      
<!-- MODAL BUTTON-->
<button class="js-modal-trigger" data-target="modal-js-examplem">
  Open JS example modal
</button>
<!-- MODAL BUTTON-->
<button class="chat-button" id="chat-btn">
  <span class="icon is-small"><i class="fas fa-comments"></i></span>
  <span class="chat-button-text">Investment Feed</span>
  <span class="icon is-small is-hidden-touch"><i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i></span>
</button>

<div id="chat-container" class="column is-2-desktop is-12-mobile">
  <div class="chat-header">
    <p class="chat-header-title has-text-black">Investement Feed</p>
    <button id="chat-close" class="delete"></button>
  </div>

  <div class="tabs">
    <ul>
      <li class="is-active" data-tab="tab-1"><a>Ideas</a></li>
      <li data-tab="tab-2"><a>Analysis</a></li>
      <li data-tab="tab-3"><a>News</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
      
<div class="chat-body">

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab-1" class="tab-panel is-active">
      <p>Tab 1 content goes here</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-2" class="tab-panel">
      <p>Tab 2 content goes here</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-3" class="tab-panel">
      <p>Tab 3 content goes here</p>
    </div>

    </div>
        <div class="chat-footer has-background-white">
          <p>Morpher does not endorse the posts shown here. <a href="#" id="disclaimer-link">Disclaimer</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</div>

<div id="modal-js-examplem" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-background"></div>

  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="box">
      <p>Modal JS example</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button class="modal-close is-large" aria-label="close"></button>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Just copied your code into vscode and ran it with live server. The modal works for me. So your problem might lay elsewhere

Comment: Just in case: you're closing `<head>` twice, and you're closing a `<div>` without opening it.